# Polymer project with web2py

Tags: python, polymer, web2py

I'm using polymer-project together with web2py. Both use {{}} for data bindings. I know you can change the delimiters in web2py but is there any way to do this is polymer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can not change the delimiters in Polymer from their default of the 'mustache' symbol ({{). There is an open issue with the project to allow for this, so it may be implmented in the future:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/718

Comment: @Frenetic can you share some example of how you use Polymer in combination with web2py?